# PowerPoint not embedding whole music clip

Tags: audio, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I'm creating a PowerPoint presentation in which I must include a 30 second sound file.

It's not important whether or not the file is embedded or linked, as the presentation will be local, but no matter which way I do it, the sound file is clipped at 20 seconds.

I do have other animations on the slide, but all of them are set to either `start on click` or `start with previous`, and none of the animations have any delay set.

The original file is fine and plays the full 30 seconds, but in PowerPoint when I look at the 'Sound Settings' in says `Total playing time: 00:20`

Does anyone know why PowerPoint may be doing this? Thanks.